# Splitting List in Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, split

I have a list which output like this

```
[                   0
0                 PV
1               Conf
2                 32
3                 PF
4               Test
5             Output
6           I/O Test,                    0
0             PVER-I
1          PVER-Conf
2                BFT
3             PVER-F
4           COM Test
5  Output State Test]
```

I want to split it as 0
so list output should be

```
[[0 PV, 1 Conf,2 32,.....],[0 PVER-1,......5 Output State Test]]
```

I tried doing this 
 My previous 2 line codes are

```
    dfo= pd.DataFrame(df_z9[0].str.split().values.tolist())
    list.append(dfo)
```

I did append here because every iteration a new list was created in dfo to add this to the list i used append and then I tried to split it at 0

```
for item in list 
    item.split('0', 1)[0]
```

It says this error Dataframe has no variable split

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `split` operation for `strings`, but not for `dataframes`. Assuming that your original list contains `string` elements, you can try to use `split` directly on this list (without the conversion to a `dataframe`):

```
out_list = [[]]
sublist = 0
for item in list:
  if item.split('0')[0] == '' and item is not list[0]:
      out_list.append([])
      sublist += 1
  out_list[sublist].append(item)
```

This will append a new sublist to the output list every time the condition is met (except for the first time).

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly. This saved a lot of time for me.